# Bluemix Deployment

Tags: ibm-cloud, couchdb, cloudant, couchdb-nano

I am getting this error when I try to connect to Cloudant on Bluemix.I am running my connection on a proxy server .

```
    [ { _id: 'key1', value: 'value1', lastUpdateTime: '1453920638633' },
      { _id: 'key2', value: 'value2', lastUpdateTime: '1458930608633' },
      { _id: 'key3', value: 'value3', lastUpdateTime: '1438820618633' } ]
    { [Error: error happened in your connection]
      name: 'Error',
      scope: 'socket',
      errid: 'request',
      code: 'ECONNRESET',
      description: 'tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO 140255972800384:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:794:\n',
      stacktrace: 
       [ 'Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO 140255972800384:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:794:',
         '',
         '    at ClientRequest.onError (/home/turbo/Gitrepo/topcoder1/admin/node_modules/cloudant/node_modules/nano/node_modules/request/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:176:17)',
         '    at ClientRequest.g (events.js:260:16)',
         '    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)',
         '    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)',
         '    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:267:9)',
         '    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)',
         '    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:169:7)',
         '    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:312:10)',
         '    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:330:5)',
         '    at WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:89:5)' ] }
    Failed to insert into game database: error happened in your connection
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to connect to Cloudant? Please be sure to remove any credentials if defined.